# Agent Lotus error with lotusscript Shell command: File not found

Tags: linux, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-designer

I am trying to execute a file with extension .sh on linux system by lotus script agent using the command 'Shell(parameter)' passing the path of file as parameter, but after perform the agent, the following error appears on domino console: file not found.The problem is that the file is on the path and if I try to execute it manually from console of linux it works. What could be the reason of this message?

Comment: Maybe the account context you are under when you manually launch the console is different than the context used by Domino, and the Domino account doesn't have access?

Comment: Hello Ken, thank's for your reply, but in this case the file with extension .sh is owned by domino user  and is located under notesdata folder, so i think that the permission isn't a problem...

Comment: Have you tried using '/bin/sh /full/path/myscript.sh' as the parameter?

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks for you reply. Follow my code:
Sub Initialize

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks for your reply. Follow my code:
Sub Initialize
   Dim cmd as String
   Dim x as variant
   x = Shell("/bin/sh /local/notesdata/shell.sh")
End Sub

The problem still remains.

My Linux is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server Release 6.3 (Santiago) and Domino 9.01 FP5.

Comment: Do you have access to the server to log in and look at the filesystem? If so, try something like "/bin/sh ls > myuniquename-output.txt". If that seems to run without error, log in and find your file to make sure. The idea here is to decide whether the "file not found" is complaining about not finding the shell!

Comment: I tryed this command: x = Shel("/bin/sh ls > /local/notesdata/test.txt") but still remains the same error.

Comment: Hmmm... It sounds to me like the Shell() is not finding *any* files. Is the agent set to "Do not allow restricted operations" and do you (the agent signer) have "Sign or run restricted LotusScript/Java agents" enabled in the server document?

Comment: Hello, I change the lotuscript agent by java agent. I used ProcessBuilder class and it works! My lotusscript agent was with maximum permission and the user that signed too. So, I think that with lotusscript is not possible perform this action. It may be that it works best on windows system. Thank you guys.